# A question regarding work-energy theorem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, work

I am sort of confused regarding which height to use in the work of a certain force if we took the variation of two kinetic energies. Suppose $\Delta KE_{A \rightarrow B}=\sum W\vec{f}$ then, do we use $mgh_{A}$ or $mgh_{B}$ when calculating the work of weight? I'll give a short example below:

**Given:** $m=0.1kg, g=10m/s^2, \alpha=30^\circ, OA=4cm, ME_O=9j, ME_A=4j$ 
The question is, **The solid (S) is under a constant force of friction of magnitude *f*. Find *f*.** 
The answer is supposed to be $1.25N$.
$KE_O=ME_O-GPE_O=9-OAsin\alpha=9-4sin30=7j$ 
$KE_A=ME_A-GPE_A=4-0=4j$ 
$\Delta KE_{O \rightarrow A}=W\vec{mg}+W\vec{N}+W\vec{f}$ 
$KE_A-KE_O=mgh_{A}+0+(-f).OA$ 
$4-7=0+0-4f$ 
$-f=-\frac{3}{4}$ 
$f=0.75N$ (which is incorrect)

If we attempt to use $mgh_{O}$ instead, we'd get the correct answer: 
$\Delta KE_{O \rightarrow A}=W\vec{mg}+W\vec{N}+W\vec{f}$ 
$KE_A-KE_O=mgh_{O}+0+(-f).OA$ 
$4-7=2+0-4f$ 
$-f=-\frac{5}{4}$ 
$f=1.25N$ (which is correct) 
How do I know which height to choose when calculating the work of weight? Is there some sort of factor? For instance, whether the body is ascending or descending, the choice of non-zero reference, and so on.

[image: A ball descending an inclined plane]

Comment: What is the question regarding the work energy theorem?

Comment: The first and last lines are supposed to be the questions about work-energy theorem. Could it be that I did not ask the question properly? Or does it actually have nothing to do with work-energy theorem?

Comment: What are $ME_0$ and $ME_A$?

Comment: ME is Mechanical Energy and GPE is Gravitational Potential Energy

Comment: What do you mean by mechanical energy subscript O and mechanical energy subscript A? What do the 9j and 4j values represent?

Comment: The Mechanical Energy at point O and A with values of 9 and 4 respectively. If there seems to be a lack of information, I could possibly send a screenshot of the entire exercise with its solved answers.

Comment: Mechanical energy can refer to kinetic energy, potential energy, or the sum of the two.  It's really not clear what this problem is asking.

Comment: Yeah—ME is considered the sum of both KE and GPE in my guide book. "How do I know which height to choose when calculating the work of weight?" Apparentely, when calculating the work of weight at a certain point, I get results different from when calculating it on another point. My question is, how do I know which point must I take when calculating the work of a force in work-energy theorem. Like the $mgh_{A}$ and $mgh_{O}$ example in the problem above. The former led to a wrong answer while the latter led to the right one.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is asking. But the work energy theorem states that the net work done on an object equals its change in kinetic energy. Two things are doing work on the body going down the incline: (1) gravity, which is doing positive work since the direction of the component of the force of gravity acting down the plane is the same as the direction of the displacement of the body and (2) kinetic friction, which is doing negative work since the direction of its force is opposite the direction of the displacement of the body.

Comment: The reason it is just using MgHo is because in reality it is (MgHo-MgHa) since we are calculating  Change in the potential energy.  Since MgHa is 0 as A is on  the ground, the whole thing just becomes MgHa

Comment: To answer your question in general, if you want to calculate the change of mechanical energy between two points say, A and B, then you are going to have to add the work done by all the forces between points A and B. If the forces are friction and gravity only, then you would need to calculate the work done by friction during the distance between A to B as work by friction depends on the path taken. The work done by gravity will only depend on the difference of the heights between point A and B as it is path independant. So You will write Mg(Hb-Ha). In your case  Hb-Ha  is OAsin alpha.

Answer (score 1):

The notation you are using, or the book's, is just horribly confusing. If you just choose a better way to write things, there would not be this confusion at all.

The work done by a force over a displacement is the integral of the force dotted with the displacement. $W=\int\vec F\cdot\vec{\mathrm dr}$, and the dot product means we have to take the cosine of the angle between $\vec F$ and $\vec{\mathrm dr}$. This cosine business is sometimes easier thought of as the projection of the force onto the direction of the displacement, but in the case of weight, it is always the opposite, the projection of the displacement onto the weight. These two projections are always equivalent, and we simply do whichever is easier to see.

In the introductory stuff as you are doing, the displacement is a straight line and the force is a constant over the entire displacement, so $W=\vec F\cdot\int\vec{\mathrm dr}=\vec F\cdot\vec s$

Now, the moment you write down a potential energy, the force that has been converted into potential form, you stop worrying about the work done by it. In effect, what is happening is that the specific type of work done is formalised and automatically handled by the potential energy term, and thus you do not have to manually integrate this work done any more.

---

With all that out of the way, you should just be writing the full Conservation of Energy equation:
\begin{align}
\text{CoE}:\qquad\sum E_\text{initial}+\text{WD}&=\sum E_\text{final}\\
KE_i+GPE_i-f|\vec{OA}|&=KE_f+GPE_f\\
KE_O+GPE_O-f\ell&=KE_A+GPE_A\\
(KE_O+GPE_O)-(KE_A+GPE_A)&=f\ell\\
f&=\frac{ME_O-ME_A}\ell\\
 &=\frac{(9-4)\,\text J}{4\,\text m}=1.25\,\text N
\end{align}
which means that you did not even need to extract the KE and GPE of them separately. And seriously, almost nobody ever uses ME as mechanical energy. We almost always write down the different energies.

As for the GPE, there is a choice of the level at which you define the GPE to be zero. The entire horizontal line passing through $A$ has $GPE_A$, and the entire horizontal line passing through $O$ has $GPE_O$. Let us define height $h=|\vec{OA}|\sin\alpha=2\,\text m$, then what you have is that
$$GPE_O-GPE_A=mgh$$
where I have written things so that you may pick any level you like to be zero. It is, of course, normal to pick $GPE_A=0$ for your problem.

It is very weird that your thing is dropping down the incline and yet it is losing kinetic energy.

Answer (score 0):

The work of the net force equals the change of kinetic energy. That change is given.

Now we have to calculate the work of the net force. In this type of problems, where the displacement is constrained, it is useful to take only the components of the forces on the allowable displacement, the incline. The Normal force and the component of the weight perpendicular to the incline do no work because they are orthogonal to displacement.

So, subtracting the component of the weight along the incline from the friction force, and multiplying by the length of the incline, we have the work of the net force.
It was done in the second approach, (but not explicitly) because $$(mgsin(\alpha) - f_A)OA = mgsin(\alpha)OA - f_AOA$$ $$mgsin(\alpha)\frac{h_0}{sin{\theta}} - f_AOA = mgh_0 - f_AOA$$